# How do I undo a speedmult console use?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I did `player.forceav speedmult 10000000` as a joke and now I can't play.
The character is stuck in a infinite running loop. How do I undo this so I can continue my game?

Comment: *player* sorry about that

Comment: You can edit your question if you made a mistake, I did it for you now. :)

Comment: So you're saying `forceav` didn't work? That's the answer that's linked in the duplicate marked question... `player.forceav speedmult 100`